# Docker -- tried to fix issue, made it much worse

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm running a MacOS. I'm not very familiar with docker and I was following the online examples on how to use docker files when I followed a trail of bad internet advice and ended up here...
I'm trying to install and run this open sourced project: https://github.com/agrimgupta92/derl
run the docker command:

`docker build -t derl ~Desktop/derl/docker`
But I'm getting the following error:

```
[+] Building 0.1s (2/2) FINISHED                                                         
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 37B                                                 0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                   0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                     0.0s
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: base name ($PARENT_IMAGE) should not be blank
```

This seems like something to fix in the docker file of the github and I'm not experienced enough to know what to do.

Comment: you should build the image using this script, it invokes a couple of arguments variables that are needed to build your image
https://github.com/agrimgupta92/derl/blob/main/scripts/build_docker.sh

Comment: Thank you! Could you be more specific on what you mean by build? like: `docker build -t derl ./scripts/build_docker.sh`, if so I get: `failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: error from sender: walk scripts/build_docker.sh: not a directory`

Comment: check the content of the script - it has all the necessary commands to build the image. you do not need to run docker build command; however, if you want to run the docker build command, you would need to pass build-args as mentioned in the script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is your command to build the image

```
set -x

PARENT=ubuntu:16.04
TORCH=cpuonly
TAG=derl
USER_ID=`id -u`

docker build -f ~Desktop/derl/docker/Dockerfile \
  --build-arg PARENT_IMAGE=${PARENT} \
  --build-arg TORCH=${TORCH} \
  --build-arg USER_ID=${USER_ID} \
  -t ${TAG} ~Desktop/derl/docker/
```